# re Libre Office Writer top toolbar highligter

Tags: libreoffice

How can I get my highlighter icon back on the top toolbar? (It's not there anymore.)
Also, when I have used the highlighter, how do I get it to stop highlighting? How do turn it off?

Answer (score 0):

To show or hide the highlighting icon:

View --> Toolbars --> Customize

Then select the Toolbars tab, then the formatting toolbar from the drop-down menu and tick the dezired icon.

[image]

To stop the highlighter from highlighting just click again on the highlighter icon.